RequestError from got package throwing error while extending
I am facing an issue while trying to extend the RequestError class. The super constructor call is giving me an issue as mentioned below
 import {RequestError, NormalizedOptions } from 'got';
    
class NetworkError extends RequestError{
        constructor(err:RequestError, request: Request | NormalizedOptions){
            super(err.message,err,request);
        }
}



The error is telling you that the err.request property is undefined. Unfortunately there's not enough detail in the question to help you debug why that's happening.

updated the question details. Please check the image

I think you are trying to use the standard Node.js Request type.
Try importing Request from got package.
Using the latest got version ("got": "^14.3.0"), these are the typings that work:
import {Options, RequestError, Request } from 'got';
    
class NetworkError extends RequestError{
        constructor(err:RequestError, request: Request | Options){
            super(err.message,err,request);
        }
}

